# Как анимировать фигуры из paintevent?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, анимация, qpropertyanimation

Я пытался решить проблему с наследованием переменной и когда мне это удавалось - возникали ошибки в самой библиотеке *Qt*.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQuick
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        if self.flagPaintEvent:   
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(100, 250, 250), 1, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.setBrush(QColor(250, 250, 250))
            painter.drawRect(90, 110, 340, 280)
        self.update()

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setFixedSize(1300, 800)
        self.setUpdatesEnabled(True)

        self.flagPaintEvent = True
    
    def foo(self):
        self.do_anim2()

    def do_anim2(self):
        self.block2 = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(painter, b'geometry', self)
        self.block2.setStartValue(QRect(75, 30, 16, 16))
        self.block2.setEndValue(QRect(75, 25, 16, 16))
        self.block2.setDuration(150)
        self.block2.start()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: paintEvent -- ручное рисование на виджете, если вы хотите анимировать, то нужно будет руками это делать. Например, менять координаты, размеры, цвет и т.п. виджетов, вызывая перерисовку виджета, чтобы был вызов paintEvent

Comment: @gil9red меня это как раз устраивает, можно пример кода?

Comment: Посмотрите: 
https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/24ca921c776d356382034ee7c0267538733f6df7/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyq5__simple_balls__with_part_transparent_body.py#L117

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не совсем понял, какие фигуры вы хотите анимировать, но приведу пример, который должен вам помочь.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class CustomRect(QtWidgets.QGraphicsObject):
    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(20, 20, 340, 280) 

    def paint(self, painter, styles, widget=None):
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(100, 250, 250), 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(250, 250, 150))
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())


class Demo(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()

        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 700, 600) 

        self.rect = CustomRect()

        self.ellipse = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem()
        self.ellipse.setRect(100, 180, 100, 50)
        self.scene.addItem(self.rect)
        self.scene.addItem(self.ellipse)
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
            self.rect,
            b"pos",
            duration=4000,
            startValue=QtCore.QPointF(0, 0),                      
            endValue=QtCore.QPointF(340, 280),                     
            loopCount=-1,
        )
        self.animation.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.resize(700, 600)
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> например перерисовывать qpainter, не могли бы вы показать это в коде?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQuick
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.flagPaintEvent = True

        self.rect = (90, 110, 340, 280)
        btn = QPushButton("Click me", self, clicked=self.onClick)

        self.how_many_times = 50
        self.timer = QTimer(interval=30)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.tick)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        if self.flagPaintEvent:   
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(100, 250, 250), 1, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.setBrush(QColor(250, 250, 250))
#            painter.drawRect(90, 110, 340, 280)
            painter.drawRect(*self.rect)

            self.update()

    def tick(self):
        self.how_many_times -= 1
        if self.how_many_times:
            delta = (50-self.how_many_times)*3
            self.rect = (90 + delta, 110 + delta, 340, 280)
        else: 
            self.timer.stop()
            self.how_many_times = 50

    def onClick(self):
        self.timer.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
    main.resize(700, 600)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне нужно анимировать qpainter, без qgraphics этого не сделать?

Comment: например перерисовывать qpainter, не могли бы вы показать это в коде?

Comment: @whyeaye я добавил один из вариантов

Comment: Не стоит вызывать `self.update()` в `paintEvent`. Лучше перенести в `def tick(self):`. И зачем нужен `self.flagPaintEvent = True`, мб убрать?